# Formatting dates using XPath

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, soapui

I have the following xpath expressions...

```
//ns:response[1]/ns:return[1]/legs[1]/startDate[1] (Value 01/01/2011)
//ns:response[1]/ns:return[1]/legs[1]/startTime[1] (Value 12:13)
```

I need to format and concat these values into something like this

```
2011-08-25T17:35:00
```

Is this possible to do using xpath functions? An example would be appreciated.

The date format in the input data is dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: What XPath version do you use?

Comment: Not sure, its whats included in SoapUI 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As by @Michael Key suggestion (+1), three `substring()` and one `concat()` is all what you need. Check at this XSLT example using the XPath you are searching for (use of variables to make expression readable):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="sD" select="'01/01/2011'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="sT" select="'12:13'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(
        substring($sD,7),'-',
        substring($sD,4,2),'-',
        substring($sD,1,2),'T',
        $sT,':00')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate how and where you implimented this in SOAPUI?

Answer (score 4):

It would help to know whether your 01/01/2011 is d/m/y or m/d/y. Either way, it's just a question of calling substring() three times to extract the parts of the data, and then concat() to build up the result.

Answer (score 0):

Look at XPath 1.0 functions: `concat`, `substring`, `substring-before`, `substring-after`.