# XSLT to transform xml to xml pulling out specific values and mapping to new format

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transform

I am looking for some help with XSLT to transform one xml file into another format.

The input xml file is below:

```
<PATIENTLIST ELAPSEDMS="234" >
    <PATIENT ID="MGH000007">
        <ADDRESS1>550 BREZHNEV ST</ADDRESS1>
        <ADDRESS2></ADDRESS2>
        <CITY>MOSCOW</CITY>
        <STATE>MA</STATE>
        <ZIP>02139</ZIP>
        <COUNTRY ISO3166-1="USSR"></COUNTRY>
        <DATEOFBIRTH>1934/04/10</DATEOFBIRTH>
        <DAYPHONE>(617) 111-1111 </DAYPHONE>
        <FIRSTNAME>TEST</FIRSTNAME>
        <HOMEPHONE>(617) 111-1111</HOMEPHONE>
        <LASTNAME>TEST MGH</LASTNAME>
        <LIMITEDACCESS>False</LIMITEDACCESS>
        <MARITALSTATUS>SINGLE</MARITALSTATUS>
        <MEDICALRECORDNUMBERS>
            <MEDICALRECORDNUMBER>
                <SITE>BWH</SITE>
                <STATUS>A</STATUS>
                <VALUE>0000007</VALUE>
            </MEDICALRECORDNUMBER>
            <MEDICALRECORDNUMBER>
                <SITE>BWI</SITE>
                <STATUS>A</STATUS>
                <VALUE>0000007</VALUE>
            </MEDICALRECORDNUMBER>
            <MEDICALRECORDNUMBER>
                <SITE>MEEI</SITE>
                <STATUS>A</STATUS>
                <VALUE>0000007</VALUE>
            </MEDICALRECORDNUMBER>
            <MEDICALRECORDNUMBER>
                <SITE>MGH</SITE>
                <STATUS>A</STATUS>
                <VALUE>0000007</VALUE>
            </MEDICALRECORDNUMBER>
            <MEDICALRECORDNUMBER>
                <SITE>SHC</SITE>
                <STATUS>A</STATUS>
                <VALUE>0000007</VALUE>
            </MEDICALRECORDNUMBER>
            <MEDICALRECORDNUMBER>
                <SITE>OLD #</SITE>
                <STATUS>M</STATUS>
                <VALUE>0000007</VALUE>
            </MEDICALRECORDNUMBER>
        </MEDICALRECORDNUMBERS>
        <MIDDLEINITIAL>R</MIDDLEINITIAL>
        <MOTHERSMAIDENNAME></MOTHERSMAIDENNAME>
        <MRNR>0000007</MRNR>
        <NAME>TEST MGH, TEST R</NAME>
        <NAMESUFFIX></NAMESUFFIX>
        <NAMEPREFIX></NAMEPREFIX>
        <PRIMARYCAREPROVIDERID>512513</PRIMARYCAREPROVIDERID>
        <PRIMARYLANGUAGE>ENGLISH</PRIMARYLANGUAGE>
        <RACE CODE1="BLACK" CODE2="" FREETEXT="">BLACK</RACE>
        <ETHNICITY CODE1="AFRICAN AMERICAN" CODE2="" FREETEXT="">AFRICAN AMERICAN</ETHNICITY>
        <RELIGION>NO PREFERENCE</RELIGION>
        <SEX>M</SEX>
        <SSN></SSN>
        <UID>101662537</UID>
        <VETERAN>NO</VETERAN>
    </PATIENT>
</PATIENTLIST>
```

The output file needs to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<eCliPSEDataIntegrationServiceRequest xmlns="http://iocent.com/eCliPSEDataIntegrationServiceRequest.xsd">
    <PatientIdentifierRecord MedicalRecordNumber="MGH000007" LastName="Person" FirstName="Test" MiddleInitial="A" DateOfBirth="04/10/1934" Operation="Add" OverwriteExistingData="true" />
    <PatientDataRecord MedicalRecordNumber="MGH000007" ParameterName="Gender" ParameterValue="2" TimeStamp="8/30/2011" Operation="Add" OverwriteExistingData="true" />
    <PatientDataRecord MedicalRecordNumber="MGH000007" ParameterName="Race" ParameterValue="1" TimeStamp="8/30/2011" Operation="Add" OverwriteExistingData="true" />
</eCliPSEDataIntegrationServiceRequest>
```

So I am looking to pull out the

Patient ID and use it as the MedicalRecordNumber= value

DATEOFBIRTH node as the DateOfBirth value - with format changed from YYYY/MM/DD to MM/DD/YYYY

FIRSTNAME node becomes value for FirstName

LASTNAME node becomes value for LastName

MIDDLEINITIAL node becomes value for MiddleInitial

SEX node becomes value for Gender Male=1, Female=2

RACE node becomes Value for Race - based on a lookup table (Caucasian=1,Afican American=2, etc.) -

So I need to pull out these values, get the format changed, in some cases do a table-like translation (for gender and race), and write the file out in the new format.

I am limited to XSLT 1.0

I am very new to XSLT and so any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify **Gender** and **Race** nodes? They are not present in the sample output.

Comment: Yes - value of 
Gender comes from Sex node 
Race from Race
in orignal xml file

Comment: your XML sample output has not the correct values then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on feedback - I am updating my solution and posting here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
  <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

  <xsl:variable name='MRN'>
    <xsl:value-of select="PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/MRNR"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name='BirthDate'>
    <xsl:value-of select="PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/DATEOFBIRTH"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="BDayYear" select="substring($BirthDate,1,4)" />
  <xsl:variable name="BDayMonth" select="substring($BirthDate,6,2)" />
  <xsl:variable name="BDayDay" select="substring($BirthDate,9,2)" />

  <xsl:variable name='BirthDateUse'>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($BDayMonth, '/', $BDayDay, '/', $BDayYear)"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name='Gender'>
    <xsl:if test="translate(PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/SEX, $smallcase, $uppercase)='M'">1</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="translate(PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/SEX, $smallcase, $uppercase)='F'">2</xsl:if>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name='RaceUC'>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/RACE, $smallcase, $uppercase)"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name='Race'>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$RaceUC='WHITE'">1</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$RaceUC='BLACK'">2</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$RaceUC='AFRICAN AMERICAN'">2</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$RaceUC='HISPANIC'">3</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$RaceUC='ASIAN'">4</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$RaceUC='NATIVE AMERICAN'">5</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$RaceUC='INDIAN'">6</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>7</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name='Operation'>
    <xsl:value-of select="'Add'"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name='Overwrite'>
    <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <eCliPSEDataIntegrationServiceRequest xmlns="http://iocent.com/eCliPSEDataIntegrationServiceRequest.xsd">
      <PatientIdentifierRecord
        MedicalRecordNumber="{$MRN}"
        LastName="{PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/LASTNAME}"
        FirstName="{PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/FIRSTNAME}"
        MiddleInitial="{PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/MIDDLEINITIAL}"
        DateOfBirth ="{$BirthDate}"
        Operation="{$Operation}"
        OverwriteExistingData="{$Overwrite}"
      />
      <PatientDataRecord
          MedicalRecordNumber="{$MRN}"
          ParameterName="Gender" ParameterValue="{$Gender}"
          Operation="{$Operation}"
          OverwriteExistingData="{$Overwrite}"
          />
      <PatientDataRecord
        MedicalRecordNumber="{$MRN}"
        ParameterName="Race_7_Groups" ParameterValue="{$Race}"
        Operation="{$Operation}"
        OverwriteExistingData="{$Overwrite}"
        />
    </eCliPSEDataIntegrationServiceRequest>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you for the feedback and suggestions.

This version handles case conversion/comparison as well as formatting the bday in a format that I needed.

I like the AVT syntax to simplify the code and the  to remove the "manual formatting" that I was doing - thanks for those tips!

Comment: The right way to say thanks to useful answers here is by upvoting them ;-). You are welcome anyway. +1 for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the start that I received above.  I am posting the xslt that I came up with to solve my problem below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name='newline'><xsl:text> 
</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name='MRN'>
    <xsl:value-of select="PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/@ID"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name='Gender'>
    <xsl:if test="PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/SEX='M'">1</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/SEX='F'">2</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name='RaceIn'>
   <xsl:value-of select="PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/RACE"/>
 </xsl:variable>  

<xsl:variable name='Race'>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$RaceIn='WHITE'">1</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$RaceIn='BLACK'">2</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$RaceIn='HISPANIC'">3</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$RaceIn='ASIAN'">4</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$RaceIn='NATIVE AMERICAN'">5</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$RaceIn='INDIAN'">5</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>7</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name='CurrDate'>
    <xsl:value-of select="'MM/DD/YYY'"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name='Operation'>
    <xsl:value-of select="'Add'"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name='Overwrite'>
    <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
</xsl:variable>




  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
      <eCliPSEDataIntegrationServiceRequest >
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
        <PatientIdentifierRecord>
          <xsl:attribute name="MedicalRecordNumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="$MRN"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="LastName">
            <xsl:value-of select="PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/LASTNAME"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="FirstName">
            <xsl:value-of select="PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/FIRSTNAME"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="MiddleInitial">
            <xsl:value-of select="PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/MIDDLEINITIAL"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="DateOfBirth">
            <xsl:value-of select="PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/DATEOFBIRTH"/> <!-- do we need to change the date format?-->
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="Operation">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Operation"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="OverwriteExistingData">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Overwrite"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </PatientIdentifierRecord>
        <xsl:text>
            </xsl:text>
          <PatientDataRecord>
            <xsl:attribute name="MedicalRecordNumber">
              <xsl:value-of select="$MRN"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ParameterName">
              <xsl:value-of select="'Gender'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ParameterValue">
              <xsl:value-of select="$Gender"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Timestamp">
              <xsl:value-of select="$CurrDate"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Operation">
              <xsl:value-of select="$Operation"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="OverwriteExistingData">
              <xsl:value-of select="$Overwrite"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </PatientDataRecord>
        <xsl:text>
            </xsl:text>
        <PatientDataRecord>
          <xsl:attribute name="MedicalRecordNumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="$MRN"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ParameterName">
            <xsl:value-of select="'Race'"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ParameterValue">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Race"/>           <!-- this needs to be transformed based on race table and race_7_groups parameter -->
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="Timestamp">
            <xsl:value-of select="$CurrDate"/>                  <!-- how do i get the current date?-->
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="Operation">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Operation"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="OverwriteExistingData">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Overwrite"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </PatientDataRecord>
        <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
      </eCliPSEDataIntegrationServiceRequest>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am still working on a solution to get the current date.  Options I have looked at
- passing in as parameter
- writing a script function to get the current date

Also, I am not sure yet if I need to change the format of the date from YYYY/MM/DD to MM/DD/YYYY.

If anyone has some suggestions on the two topics above, they would be welcomed.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started down the right path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="PATIENTLIST">
        <xsl:for-each select="PATIENT">                                             
            <eCliPSEDataIntegrationServiceRequest>
                <xsl:attribute name="xmlns">
                    http://iocent.com/eCliPSEDataIntegrationServiceRequest.xsd
                </xsl:attribute>
                <PatientIdentifierRecord>
                    <xsl:attribute name="MedicalRecordNumber">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    ...
                    <xsl:for-each select="MEDICALRECORDNUMBER">
                        <xsl:attribute name="MedicalRecordNumber">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        ...
                    </xsl:for-each>                                             
                </PatientIdentifierRecord>
            </eCliPSEDataIntegrationServiceRequest>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You will probably need some hard coded `<xsl:if test="SEX='MALE'">1</xsl:if>` statements to do the "enum" switching

Comment: Thanks very much for getting me started!  I am going to follow up with a post for what I ended up creating to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few hints.

Use AVT syntax to simplify your code. Example:

```
    <PatientIdentifierRecord
      MedicalRecordNumber="{$MRN}"
      LastName="{PATIENTLIST/PATIENT/LASTNAME}"
     ...
    />
```

For line feed, use code from ISO-8859-1 character set:

```
<xsl:variable name="lf" select="'&#10;'"/>
```

For date-time see this [**topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575111/can-an-xslt-insert-the-current-date) and check your parser documentation.

If you need to change date format, use `substring()` and `concat()` function. Check [**this similar topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187564/formatting-dates-using-xpath/7190557#7190557).

It seems that you are using line feed to indent your code. For this job you have a proper instruction (which might be supported depending on your parser):

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
```